# Deploying Fb app on Heroku

Tags: php, facebook, git, heroku, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm new to Heroku. For sometimes I've been trying to deploy an app on Heroku for Fb but have not seen success. I've tried searching for solution on the internet but have not found any **step by step guide**, so I'm asking here.

My Fb App code "index.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/fbsdk/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '************',
'app_secret' => '**********',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',]);
 $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
 $permissions = ['email']; 

try {
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
$accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
} else {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
}
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {

if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
} else {
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
}

try {
    $request = $fb->get('/me');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
        unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/', $permissions);
        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
        exit;
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
}

try {
    $requestPicture = $fb->get('/me/picture?redirect=false&height=300'); 
    $requestProfile = $fb->get('/me');
    $picture = $requestPicture->getGraphUser();
    $profile = $requestProfile->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
}

echo "<img src='".$picture['url']."'/>";
} else {
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/');
echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
 }
```

"composer.json"

```
 {}
```

Commands I used on Git Bash

```
heroku create AppName
mkdir AppName
cd AppName
git init
git add .
git commit -m "comment"
heroku git:remote -a AppName
git push heroku master

git branch
git commit -am "comment"
git push heroku master
```

Everything goes well, heroku compiles the PHP files, deploys the file. But when I open the Fb app or even the heroku app address directly it shows a **403 Forbidden" message [fbapp-2.herokuapp.com](http://fbapp-2.herokuapp.com)

The directory structure 
[image]

Buildpacks set as **heroku/php**
I dont have procfile or .htaccess file

heroku logs shows

```
State changed from starting to up
2016-04-05T15:30:14.413923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/"             host=fbapp-2.herokuapp.com request_id=ea94baf1-a433-4631-bbe5-7493cb7e137f   wd="43.230.135.148" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=403 bytes=373
2016-04-05T15:30:14.399879+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Apr 05 15:30:14.395964 2016] [autoindex:error] [pid 82:tid 139840075028224] [client 1.3.2.3:58066] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
2016-04-05T15:30:14.400023+00:00 app[web.1]: 1.3.2.3 - - [05/Apr/2016:15:30:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.46
2016-04-05T15:30:14.873648+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fbapp-2.herokuapp.com request_id=8b65b3b6-2f82-4ab4-abb4-d4849c1ec225 fwd="43.230.135.148" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=373
2016-04-05T15:30:14.856297+00:00 app[web.1]: 1.3.2.3 - - [05/Apr/2016:15:30:14 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://fbapp-2.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/36.0.2130.46
```

Comment: Before you "minus" vote the question post a STEP BY STEP guide for the current API to use on HEROKU.

Comment: Heroku has a tendency to use a single http error code for a large group of errors. To identify the issue we need you to log into your Heroku account and access the Heroku error log. It will contain errors codes starting with the letter "H".

Comment: @PlanetScaleNetworks thnx for your response.. ERROR logs added.

Comment: "AH01276: Cannot serve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error log you are getting indicates that your app is not sitting in the /app directory on the Heroku server and that there is nothing in that directory to be served. Try shifting your entire application from the web root into the /app directory and see how that goes, should solve your issue, if not reply back with an updated error log.

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understood from the error you do not have any index file inside directory you are trying to access and directory listing is disabled, so in the end you are getting `403` error.

I would suggest to try creating `.htaccess` inside directory you want to access file with:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Which is enabling a directory listing in this location.

Answer (score 1):

The logs are telling you that Heroku's Apache can't find an index file in the `/app` folder.
Move the content of `fbapp-2` inside `/app` and as you are using composer you could make sure that apache has the correct permissions by adding this to your composer config:

`"scripts": { "post-install-cmd": [ "chmod -R 755 app/" ] }`